# Optimize Web API call

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller in a Web Api 2 project:

```
[EnableQuery()]
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> Get()
{
    var items = from i in db.Items
        select new ItemDTO()
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            ...
        };
    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```

This request takes, on average, 30 ms to execute.

But, as i want to include a function call, to do some calculating, inside my controller, i had to move it out LINQ to Entities, and now have this;

```
[EnableQuery()]
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> Get()
{
    var sourceItems = db.Items.Include(x => x.locations).ToList();
    var items = sourceItems
        .Select(i => new ItemDTO()
                {
            Id = i.Id,
            ...
            Coordinates = GetCentralGeoCoordinate(i.locations
                        .Select(p => new GeoCoordinate()
                        {
                            Latitude = Double.Parse(p.cX, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Longitude = Double.Parse(p.cY, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        })
                        .ToList())
        });
    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```

But this takes, on average, around 6000ms to execute, which is way to long.
I tried removing the function call, but that made no difference - so it is not the function itself that is making it slower.

Any ideas as to how i can optimize the second example, to be as fast, as the first example?

Function that is being called (but i tried removing this entirely, and it still has en execution time of 6000ms)

```
public static Coordinate GetCentralGeoCoordinate(IList<GeoCoordinate> geoCoordinates)
        {
            var result = new Coordinate();

            if (geoCoordinates.Count == 1)
            {
                return geoCoordinates.Single()
            }

            double x = 0;
            double y = 0;
            double z = 0;

            foreach (var geoCoordinate in geoCoordinates)
            {
                var latitude = geoCoordinate.Latitude * Math.PI / 180;
                var longitude = geoCoordinate.Longitude * Math.PI / 180;

                x += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
                y += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
                z += Math.Sin(latitude);
            }

            var total = geoCoordinates.Count;

            x = x / total;
            y = y / total;
            z = z / total;

            var centralLongitude = Math.Atan2(y, x);
            var centralSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            var centralLatitude = Math.Atan2(z, centralSquareRoot);

            var centralLatitudeFinal = centralLatitude * 180 / Math.PI;
            var centralLongitudeFinal = centralLongitude * 180 / Math.PI;
            GeoCoordinate centralGeoFinal = new GeoCoordinate(centralLatitudeFinal, centralLongitudeFinal);

            return centralGeoFinal;
        }
```

Comment: What `GetCentralGeoCoordinate` its do?

Comment: it may because of `GetCentralGeoCoordinate` , but `ToList()` is expensive also.

Comment: @Aria ToList() is called when the IQueryable is returned from the controller anyway. Considering you are eagerly loading the locations with an `Include` statement, I would guess the cost of the query is roughly the same between both the first and second implementation, and that the overhead is coming from the `GetCentralGeoCoordinate` method

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan It just calculates a central point based on some Lat/Lng values - purely math, no db lockups or anything. It is not that function, that is making it slow.. even if i remove the call from my controller, it still takes 6000ms to execute. I updated the question with the function - but please note, that i am fairly sure, this is not the root of the overhead.

Comment: Add some logging to the database context, look at the generated SQL, and compare the two queries

Comment: `db.Items.Include(x => x.locations).ToList()`, why you are converting it through `ToList`. This is fetching all the items along with locations already from DB.

Comment: I notice you have the `EnableQuery` attribute on this method. Are you filtering the results of this endpoint on the client? Because if you are, the second method no longer allows the client's filtering to be translated into SQL, since you have called `ToList` within the controller method

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Yes, I am using filtering on the clientside. If i remove the ToList() i can no longer use my function call, as it is beeing processed by EF, and EF does not recognize the method. I get this error 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'GetCentralGeoCoordinate...'

Comment: Since the helper function `GetCentralGeoCoordinate` is all math, it is convertible to SQL. You'll have to do it inline in the query, which will be ugly, but at least it will allow you to do pre-filtering rather than post-filtering

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Do you have an example of how this could look?

Comment: Sorry, no - I had a go, but I found it pretty difficult. If you want to try it, you might be best to post it as a new question. I can think of two other alternatives - if your client is always filtering the same way, you could accept the filter parameters as part of the endpoint, and explicitly do it server side. Or, you could use the `DbGeometry` classes to store the data, as they have this sort of functionality built in (although I have had very bad experiences with them - google `EF sqlserver.types`, almost every link is some person having problems with the DLL)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of using ToList(), so you are retrieving all values from DB.

Also depending on your configuration, the line i.locations could  generate additional query to database for each item. So overall you will have n+1 queries to database.

I've noticed, that GetCentralGeoCoordinate function is pretty simple, so it could be converted to linq query. Something like

```
        [EnableQuery()]
        public IQueryable<ItemDTO> Get()
        {
            var rad = Math.PI / 180;
            var deg=180/Math.PI;

            return db.Items
                .Select(i => new
                {
                    i.Id,
                    x = i.Locations.Sum(t => Math.Cos(t.cX * rad) * Math.Cos(t.cY * rad)),
                    y = i.Locations.Sum(t => Math.Cos(t.cX * rad) * Math.Sin(t.cY * rad)),
                    z = i.Locations.Sum(t => Math.Sin(t.cX * rad)),
                    Count = i.Locations.Count()
                })
                .Select(i => new ItemDTO
                {
                    Id = i.Id,
                    Latitude = Math.Atan2(i.z, Math.Sqrt(i.x * i.x + i.y * i.y)) * deg,
                    Longtitude = Math.Atan2(i.y, i.x) * deg
                });
        }
```

Not sure if all translated correct, but should be something like this.
The EF will translate this to SQL and when executed, the actual locations will not be retrieved (only aggregated values). So it should be faster.